# How do I accurately extend the duration of a tiny video clip?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, pts

I noticed that ffmpeg doesn't always scale the duration of a clip to the desired value ( even accounting for milliseconds of precision loss.) For example, whenever I attempt to scale the duration of this tiny 67ms clip to 7 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter:v "setpts=(7/0.067)*PTS" -an output.avi
```

the resulting video is only 3.5 seconds in duration.

Not really sure why this is off by multiple seconds, but I suspect it has something to do with the input clip itself ( which is only 2 frames @ 29.97 fps ) So far, I've discovered that if I scale the duration to a much larger value first, then scale back from that to 7 seconds, it works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter:v "setpts=(1000)*PTS" -an input_scaled_high.avi
ffmpeg -i input_scaled_high.avi -filter:v "setpts=(7/33.400033)*PTS" -an output.avi
```

But I'm hoping I don't need to resort to an intermediate file. Is it possible to solve this with a single ffmpeg call?

If it helps, here is the video file I'm working with: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hI5Xo6kfAfMd8ZylM6XrPX5fuO88gncE?usp=sharing

Note: I should mention that I don't need sound at all in this experiment ( hence the `-an` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What setpts does is alter **P**resentation **T**ime**S**tamps. PTS is the time at which a frame is shown/drawn. The duration of a video stream is equal to the PTS of the last frame + duration of the last frame. Your file is 29.97 fps, so each frame has a duration of 0.033s.

In your first command, the 2nd frame gets a new PTS of 3.47s but its duration is still 0.033s, hence the stream has a total duration of 3.5s

In your two step process, the 2nd frame gets a PTS of 6.97s. So even though the duration is 7s, I assume this is not what you want.

The way to do this is

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter:v "setpts=(7/2)*N/TB" -r 2/7 -an output.avi
```

where `(7/2)` indicates target duration (7 seconds) and total frames (2). That fraction is reversed in the `-r` value. FFmpeg sets frame duration based on the `-r` value.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have a much better understanding of PTS now.

Comment: it is worth mentioning that (7/2)*N/TB is sort of a function that loops over all frames, takes the frame's count to get the desired pts of that frame and sets it to it. where N is the current frame count and TB stands for TimeBase which is used to convert from the video time unit to seconds.